# "You cannot invalidate constraints for an object ..." compiling storyboard via xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

When I try to build one of my schemes using XCodeBuild I am getting the following message numerous numerous times during the compilation of the storyboard:

"You cannot invalidate constraints for an object unless you are in a block that guarantees that constraints will be updated".

It builds fine within XCode, what is curious is that I have more than one scheme which is using the same storyboard and those other schemes compile fine using XCodeBuild.

I'm using XCode 4.6 and have auto layout turned off.